# converting multi dictionary from json to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following output I received from using a for loop to parse a JSON i believe. I was wondering how I could convert this output into a Dataframe

```
01E8jn7u387ZHexw2mOo => {'email': 'a4@yahoo.com ', 
'agreed_to_terms': True, 'toy_duration': 2, 'dog_name': 'Oakley', 
'dog_breeds': ['Mixed Breed / Mutt'], 'zip': '95355', 'human_name': 
'Alina'}
01WCbRaNLVVWglHopTEJ => {'zip': '45014', 'human_name': 'Neil', 
'agreed_to_terms': True, 'email': 'Nek@gmail.com ', 
'toy_duration': 0, 'dog_name': 'Maize, Georgie', 'dog_breeds': ['German 
Shorthaired Lab', 'Shih Tzu']}
02InTOWJSxfjHIPDTPdE => {'agreed_to_terms': True, 'email': 
'2@aol.com', 'toy_duration': 2, 'dog_name': 'Chewie', 
'dog_breeds': ['Shih Tzu'], 'zip': '32068', 'human_name': 'Amber'}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

looks like a job for json_normalize.

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

a = {'email': 'a4@yahoo.com ', 
'agreed_to_terms': True, 'toy_duration': 2, 'dog_name': 'Oakley', 
'dog_breeds': ['Mixed Breed / Mutt'], 'zip': '95355', 'human_name': 
'Alina'}


df_a = json_normalize(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
>>> data = [
    {
        "email": "a4@yahoo.com ",
        "agreed_to_terms": True,
        "toy_duration": 2,
        "dog_name": "Oakley",
        "dog_breeds": ["Mixed Breed / Mutt"],
        "zip": "95355",
        "human_name": "Alina",
    },
    {
        "zip": "45014",
        "human_name": "Neil",
        "agreed_to_terms": True,
        "email": "Nek@gmail.com ",
        "toy_duration": 0,
        "dog_name": "Maize, Georgie",
        "dog_breeds": ["German Shorthaired Lab", "Shih Tzu"],
    },
    {
        "agreed_to_terms": True,
        "email": "2@aol.com",
        "toy_duration": 2,
        "dog_name": "Chewie",
        "dog_breeds": ["Shih Tzu"],
        "zip": "32068",
        "human_name": "Amber",
    },
]

>>> pd.DataFrame(data)
   agreed_to_terms                          dog_breeds        dog_name           email human_name  toy_duration    zip
0             True                [Mixed Breed / Mutt]          Oakley   a4@yahoo.com       Alina             2  95355
1             True  [German Shorthaired Lab, Shih Tzu]  Maize, Georgie  Nek@gmail.com        Neil             0  45014
2             True                          [Shih Tzu]          Chewie       2@aol.com      Amber             2  32068
```

Accumulate a list of the dogs, which is easily turned into a Pandas dataframe.